# I need help to make a connexion in php

Tags: php, email, web, pdo

I'm working for a school project in php. I'm doing a connexion system for a website (the register system is already done) but my code don't work correctly. I'm french so sorry for my bad english (note: mdp means password).
Here is my connexion code:

```
<?php 

// ------ connexion à la base de données -----------------------

include('./mdp.php'); //this is the password to acces to the database

try
{$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $userpswd);}
catch(Exception $e)
{die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());}

session_start();

$email=$_POST['email'];
$mdp = md5($_POST['password']);

$req = $bdd->prepare("USE informatica_database; SELECT id,email,mdp FROM Client WHERE email like :email and mdp like :mdp");

$req->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue(':mdp', $mdp, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//echo $req;

$req->execute();
$nb = $req->rowCount();
$data= $req->fetch();
$req = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<br>";
echo "DEBUG MODE :  ";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<p>Requête: </p>", $req;
echo "<br>";
echo "<p>NB: </p>", $nb;
echo "<br>";
echo "<p>Données: </p>", $data;
echo "<br>";
echo "<p>Donnée e-mail: </p>", $data['email'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<p>Requête e-mail: </p>", $req['email'];
echo "<br>";

if (!empty($data['email'])) {

    if (password_verify($mdp, ':mdp')) {
        echo "<p>Connexion avec succès à la boutique !</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Connexion avec succès à la boutique !";
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        //header("Location: ./catalogue.php");//
        exit();
    }

    else{
        echo "<p>Le mot de passe est incorrect, veuillez réessayer à nouveau !</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Le mot de passe est incorrect, veuillez réessayer à nouveau !";
        //header("Location: ./connect.html");//
        exit();
    }
}

else {
    echo "<p>L'adresse fournie est incorrecte ou n'existe pas ! Pensez à vérifier qu'il n'y ait pas de faute.</p>";
    $_SESSION['message'] = "L'adresse fournie est incorrecte ou n'existe pas ! Pensez à vérifier qu'il n'y ait pas de faute.";
    //header("Location: ./connect.html");//
    exit();
    }

echo $nb;
echo "Traitement terminé !";

//echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=https://google.com/' />";//

?>
```

And there is the result displayed (before and after):

[image: Before]

[image: After]

But the mail exist in the database:
[image: Database row for the tested account]

I've check my html, my database, and the error seems not be there.
So can someone help me ?

Comment: There are quite a few problems with the code.  You don't need to `USE informatica_database;` part as you already select the database.  You shouldn't be selecting based on the password and you don't use `md5()`.  Your check should also compare the user entered password and the database password.

Comment: Don't you mean $data = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); instead of $req = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ? Why are you doing a fetch twice? That would just fetch two rows. I don't believe that's what you want? Do you get the expected values in the $data array?

Comment: Thanks you for your answers ! I've remove the "Use" and I've change the fetch, but this still not work, the same message that said that the mail isn't good is printed. About the md5 part, I've try with and without and I've compare to the database password and it seems that I need to keep this.